# How to install and access python module locally?

Tags: python, bash, path

Trying to follow what I understand to be best practices, I installed pipenv to be able to install a python module locally (and not break any other programs or dependencies).  Of course, I installed pipenv locally, using

```
$ pip install --user pipenv
```

Unfortunately, a subsequent call to pipenv yields the following:

```
$ pipenv install requests
-bash: pipenv: command not found
```

So pipenv isn't available in the shell, despite being freshly installed.  I believe (from googling) that the problem has to do with my PATH and perhaps I need to add my user directory to my .bashrc file?  But I'm not sure what exactly to add to the .bashrc file to fix the problem.

Comment: Why you don't use virtualenv

Comment: @Ghassen Thank you, I am trying to do just that.  According to the instructions on "The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python", this step (installing pipenv) precedes the installation and use of virtualenv.  Perhaps that's incorrect though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

pip --user installs to ~/.local/bin.

Therefore, you can add the following line to your ~/.bashrc:

> export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` or open a new terminal session and pipenv should be found.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't actually see a .bashrc file in my home directory (maybe that's the problem!).  I see .bash_history, .bash_profile, and .bash_sessions.

Comment: Are you on OSX? OSX terminals use .bash_profile instead of .bashrc because new OSX terminal sessions are launched as login sessions.  So you can apply the changes above to .bash_profile instead.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am on OSX, and I did modify my .bash_profile on your suggestion.  Have moved on to a new error.  Thank you for your help!